# Calculations for time periods SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, time

How to calculate some KPIs for a time period in SQL?

I have 3 columns:

```
Customer     CalendarWeek     Sum
```

I want to count the sum for the period from the beginning of my data to the given CW. So for 201501 it means I want to count the sum for dataset beginning of data (201301) until 201501. For 201502 from 201301 to 201502. For 201503 from 201301 to 201503 etc.

The column `CalendarWeek` is always the max week of the time period.

Basically return should look like:

```
Customer A    201501     1200
Customer A    201510     4000
Customer B    201501     200
```

Where 201501 is the end of the period for which 1200 was counted. 1200 is for Customer A from 201401 until 201501.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you were using.  Also, provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the sum up to a particular week, you can do:

```
select sum("sum")
from t
where calendarweek <= '201501';
```

If you want to do this per customer, then add `Customer` to the `select` and add `Customer` to the `group by`.

Comment: Yes, but like this I filter the whole query on <= 201501. I want for each row to have a sum for the period from 201301 until row date.

Comment: @Mats . . . Edit the question and show the query you are using, your current output, and the results you would like to get.

Comment: I edited. Still having no query, I am looking for ideas how to solve it. Probably need a sub-query for determing the period.